# vuejs emit method from component to root

Tags: vue.js

I have a component where I am trying to call a method from to the root. I have tried emitting from there but keep in mind there is no button in the HTML to trigger this.How can I emit this method without a button- where would I place the listener? I want to use this concept in a project to update the score. Please provide suggestions.

```js
Vue.component('item-edit', {
  template: '#item-edit',
  props: {
    item: Object,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      inEdit: false,
    }
  },
  methods:{
   toggle(){
     this.inEdit = !this.inEdit;
   },
   increment() {
   this.$emit(increment)
   }
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    items: [{
      id: 1,
      name: 'test-1'
    }, {
      id: 2,
      name: 'test-2'
    }, {
      id: 3,
      name: 'test-3'
    }, ],
  },
  methods:{
  increment(){
  score+=1
  }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
Score: {{score}}
  <template id="item-edit">
    <li>
      <span v-show="!inEdit">{{item.name}}</span>
      <input v-show="inEdit" type="text" v-model="item.name" />
      <a href="#" @click.prevent="toggle();">{{inEdit ? 'save' : 'edit'}}</a>
    </li>
  </template>
  <ul>
    <item-edit v-for="item in items" :item="item"></item-edit>
  </ul>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to listen to the event using on:

```
<item-edit v-for="item in items" :item="item" v-on:increment="increment">
</item-edit>
```

Now, the `v-on:increment` will call the method `increment` of that component.

```
increment() {
  score += 1
}
```

So now, how to tell the child component to emit the event?

Well, you will just emit the event from the method where you wish.

```
methodToEmit() {
  this.$emit('increment')
}
```

Your question, how will I call methodToEmit without button?

You may call it right after toggle method is applied:

```
toggle() {
  // do other stuff
  this.methodToEmit()
}
```

Or, you may bind a hidden input element and bind the method to call `methodToEmit` method in mounted hook.